# Knockout template not rendering off a computed observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Below are two knockout templates plugin and plugin2.  Both are dependent upon ko.computed observables and both observables have their deferEvaluation property set to true.  Plugin **does not** render, but plugin2 **does** render.

What needs to be changed to make plugin render (keeping deferEvaluation==true)?

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/YKLGM/

**HTML**

```
<div id="plugin" data-bind="template: { name: 'template1', data: $data }" ></div>
<div id="plugin2" data-bind="template: { name: 'template2', data: $data }" ></div>

<script type="text/html" id="template1">
    <div data-bind="foreach: columns()">
        <span data-bind="text: displayText"></span>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="template2">
    <div data-bind="text: dataItem" ></div>
</script>
```

**Javascript**

```
var gridData = {
    columns: [{
        displayText: 'Name'
    }, {
        displayText: 'Last Login Date'
    }, {
        displayText: 'Email'
    }]
};

function DataModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.columns = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.loadGrid = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            self.columns(gridData.columns);
        },
        owner: this,
        deferEvaluation: true
    });

    self.id = ko.observable(1);

    self.dataItem = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return self.id() * 3;
        },
        owner: this,
        deferEvaluation: true
    });
}

dataModel = new DataModel();
ko.applyBindings(dataModel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Both are dependent upon ko.computed observables

No, they are not. `plugin` depends only on `columns`, which is an empty observableArray that never gets populated. Maybe you should *use* your `loadGrid` computed observable somewhere.

By the way, `loadGrid` does not make much sense as computed observable in its current state, the read method does not even return anything.